# How do you set the initial value of a EnumDropDownListFor built using helper extension?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums

I followed a tutorial for MVC5 about coding a helper extension to populate dropdownlists using enums. This works perfectly until using an edit view.

On a create page I fill the ddl and select no problem. But when I want to update the value on an edit view, using a ddl filled just as on the create, I can't default the actual value (from the database) as the displayed value.

I've searched high and low but starting to think it can't be done. I'm not sure what code will help so here goes;

My ddl on the edit view

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectStatus)
```

ProjectStatus is the enum that is used to retrieve the enum value in the helper extension and populate the ddl.

So my ddl may contain statuses such as:

New,
WIP,
Rejected,
Fixed,
Closed

and my current value may = New. So when I load the edit view I would like the value New to be defaulted in to the ddl, and be able to change this value by selecting another using the ddl.

The value I would like to default to is actually in the view (model.Status). I just can't work out how to include this in the code above.

I hope this makes sense and any help appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your extension method looks like. If you want a more direct answer, you'll need to include more details on your specific implementation. That being said, here is some sample code from an edit.cshtml template on [Autoquoter.com](http://www.autoquoter.com)

```
<div class="control-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddonType)
     <div class="controls">
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AddonType, EnumHelper.SelectListFor((AddonType)Model.AddonType))
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddonType)
     </div>
</div>
```

Notice the parameter to EnumHelper.SelectListFor. We pass in the current value to the helper method. Then we add it as the final parameter to the SelectList constructor.

```
 public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>(T selected) where T : struct
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        return !t.IsEnum ? null
                         : new SelectList(BuildSelectListItems<T>(), "Value", "Text", selected.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may be interested I fixed this using jquery.

I was getting hung up on drop downs filled by enums, razor and html helpers etc. I looked at the raw html produced and approached it from that angle.

The following code works for me but I'm no expert so there may well be better solutions

```
// set initial value of Status ddl
$(document).ready(function () {
var initialValue = $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.Status)").val();
    $("select option").filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == initialValue;
    }).prop("selected", true);
});
```

I hope this helps.